# Complete word-database for Java-App to check if a word is actually a legit word, is SQL appropriate in this case?

Tags: java, sql

I am going to write a game in which I have often have to check if a string of letters is actually a word or not. My question is about how to do this the fastest with the least computation-able power as possible (for instance an old smart-phone). With if possible not much start-up time to make it a quick and responsive app.

I once did this look-up by first reading in a word-file with almost all words into an appropriate sized hash-map of around 650,000 words*. (* might be more, I am not sure if this is the exhausted list yet).

Would a SQL database be appropriate here? I am thinking of buying a book about it so I can learn and implement one. Also I have no idea how you could create a hash-map, save it for later and then load one. Is that too much of a hacker solution or is that technique used more often? So would it make sense for me to learn SQL or do it with saving a hashmap and then later restoring it.

Comment: Do you need step by step explanation?

Comment: I asked this question to get some basic advice on when to pick a database over an internal structure you programmed yourself, but also on this particular case in which you have a large word set and want to check if it contains the word as fast as possible.

If you could describe why or why not a SQL database would be appropriate here that would be great. I have yet no idea on how hard it is to create such a database so a step-by-step solution/explanation seems like too much since I yet have not explored this direction. My question is if I should explore it..

Comment: Search for "java spell checker". In general one precompiles a dictionary say in text-form to some binary format. In general such a thing is not done with a database.

Comment: "Old smartphone" means "not much space and cpu".  You will need to consider carefully how to compress your data to save space and still not use much cpu when using your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A database SQL could be appropriate if you plan to query it every time you need to check a word, but this is not the fastest solution; querying every single word slows down the response time but it should use less memory if the words number is high (you must measure the memory consumed by the db vs the memory consumed by the map). Checking if a word is inside a map is not so computationally expensive, it must calculate the hash and iterate over the array of items with the same hash.

Personally I would choose a map if the memory requirements of keeping all the words in memory can be satisfied. You can store the dictionary as plain text file (one line -> one word) and read it in a background thread when the application starts.

Answer (score 0):

If memory is an issue, this seems like a good use for a B-Tree. This allows for O(log n) search time while searching a large amount of records with minimal memory usage. For this sort of application it sounds like loading the entire thing into memory is not going to be a good idea.

Comment: Do you have any idea of how much ram a word list this size would take?

Comment: With a B-Tree it wouldn't be in RAM it would be in long term storage (flash?).